# Will Bluez 4.101 work with Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an embedded linux device I am attempting to set up a bluetooth stack on. I am using the TI CC2564b dual mode bluetooth chip. Of course, Bluez is the first choice for embedded linux.

The problem is that most of what I am seeing out there for troubleshooting my issues is to upgrade to Bluez 5.xx. As you may know, Bluez 5 and greater requires linux kernel 3.5 to work with BLE.

The link below even states that 3.5 is required for BLE period.

[The 5.0 BlueZ](https://lwn.net/Articles/531133/)

I am able to do `lescans`, and can even pair with some devices using `gatttool`, however I have been completely unsuccessful at pairing with **THE** peripheral I am trying to get to work.

When I try to connect, I get the following HCIDump:

> ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x02 dlen 6
>
> SMP: Security Request (0x0b)
>
> auth req 0x01
>
> ACL data: handle 1025 flags 0x00 dlen 6
>
> **SMP: Pairing Failed (0x05), reason 0x05, Reason Pairing Not Supported**

Can anyone tell me if there is something I am missing, or if Bluez 4.101 with Linux 3.2 is just not going to cut it?

On another note, I know the peripheral can be paired, as I have done it with my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10 (Kernel 3.5, Bluez 4.101). I have made sure my hciconfig -a matches almost exactly.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

It looks like I am able to connect to some LE devices, but not others depending on whether or not they are over an encrypted connection. The following happens when I try to enable encryption with `hciconfig`:

> root@am335x-neptune:~# hciconfig hci0 encrypt
>
> Can't set encrypt on hci0: Invalid request code (56)

Comment: The LE support in Bluez4 is incomplete. Some things may work but you are essentially rolling the dice there.

Comment: @kaylum you wrote this reply many years ago... But do you know if this is still valid today?